# Integrating CytoscapeJs with LeafletJs

Tags: javascript, leaflet, cytoscape.js

I have made a graph component in CytoscapeJS and want to have a map as an overlay. Basically I want to represent the nodes based on their co-ordinates on Map (using LeafletJs).
I have looked into the plugin (cytoscape-mapbox-gl by zakjan) and cytoscape-leaf extension (using this currently).

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: obj.attachEvent is not a function
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')
> Uncaught Error: Map container is already initialized.

I only want to integrate CytoscapeJs with LeafletJS. I don't want to add any tile layer.

Followed all the steps on the Cytoscape-leaf plugin documentation.
I have registered the function, created the instance, added the co-ordinates in the data object,rendered the Map component alongside cytoscape component, Added the lat,lng field in the data object for cytoscape node(Node Position).

```
cytoscape.use( leaflet );
```

```
   const map = useRef();
```

```
data: {
          id: ele.nodeAddr,
          label: `IP-${ele.nodeAddr}`,
          icon:Server,
          type:'parentNode',
          status:ele.status,
          lat:19.5,
          lng:72.8777,
          
        }
```

```
 const options = {
          
          container: map.current,
        
          // the data field for latitude
          latitude: 'lat',
        
          // the data field for longitude
          longitude: 'lng'
        };
        
        const leaf = cy.leaflet(options);
```

```
<div
          ref={divRef}
          style={{
            border: "1px solid",
            backgroundColor: "#f5f6fe",
            height: '600px',
          }}
        >
           <div ref={map}></div>
```

Comment: your question (the code part) is badly formatted, which makes it hard to read. Can you please format it so that is easier to read?

Comment: @ruud Made some changes, hope it's easier to read now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is independent of your code and your intended `plugins` you want to use with `cytoscape`. It may not answer your question, but it works to some extent that I consider it a good start to use cytoscapeJS within leaflet.

One issue that I found, it wont work with browsers on `iOS` or `ipadOS`. I am sorry about that. Help is welcome to solve the issues why Webkit based browsers on iOS/ipadOS do not handle cytoscape's graph like Chrome browsers on android/windows.

Code:

```js
const base_dc = 0.027589;
const lon_ext = 0.5436;
const lat_ext = 0.5436;
const lonmin = 100.3257;
const latmin = 13.4978;
const lon_cor = lon_ext * base_dc;
const lonmax = lonmin + lon_ext;
const lonmid = (lonmin + lonmax) / 2;
const lonmax2 = lonmax + lon_cor;
const latmax = latmin + lat_ext;
const latmid = (latmin + latmax) / 2;

const latlng = { lat: latmin, lng: lonmin };
const latlng2 = { lat: latmax, lng: lonmax2 };
const clatlng = { lat: latmid, lng: lonmid };
const cbottom = { lat: latmin, lng: lonmid };

var zoom = 9;
const myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.0 }); //svg or canvas

/* Cytoscape global vars */
// must match SVG viewbox w h.
// and width, height of #cyOnSvg DIV
const cy_size = 1600;
const params = {
  width: cy_size,
  height: cy_size,
  latmin: latmin,
  latmax: latmax,
  lonmin: lonmin,
  lonmax: lonmax2
};

// Update CSS to use new cy_size
let root = document.documentElement;
root.style.setProperty("--svg-width", cy_size + "px");
root.style.setProperty("--svg-height", cy_size + "px");

/* choice of maps */
var mymap = L.map("mapid", {
  renderer: myRenderer,
  preferCanvas: false
}).setView(clatlng, zoom);

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution: "Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors"
}).addTo(mymap);

const svg_pin =
  '<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12,2Z" fill="firebrick"></path></svg>';
const svgpin_Url = encodeURI("data:image/svg+xml;utf-8," + svg_pin);

const svgpin_Icon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: svgpin_Url,
  iconSize: [24, 24],
  iconAnchor: [12, 24],
  popupAnchor: [0, -22]
});

var marker2 = L.marker(latlng2, {
  renderer: myRenderer,
  icon: svgpin_Icon
  //draggable: true,
  //autoPan: true
}).addTo(mymap);
marker2.bindPopup("<b>Control_UR</b>").openPopup();
marker2.openPopup();

var marker0 = L.marker(latlng, {
  renderer: myRenderer,
  icon: svgpin_Icon
}).addTo(mymap);
marker0.bindPopup("<b>Control_LL</b>").openPopup();
marker0.openPopup();

/* Embed SVG Element in the web page */
let svgElem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svgElem.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
svgElem.setAttribute("id", "Svg0");

svgElem.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMax slice");
svgElem.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${cy_size} ${cy_size}`);

/* SVGOverlay with foreignObject-div-text */
svgElem.innerHTML = `<foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
<div id="cyOnSvg" style="background-color:rgba(200,200,200,0.25);padding:0;"></div>
<div id="upperlefttext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</div>
</foreignObject>`;
// Note: lonmax2 (=lonmax + correction)
const svgElementBounds = [
  [latmin, lonmin],
  [latmax, lonmax2]
];
const svgobj = L.svgOverlay(svgElem, svgElementBounds, {
  renderer: myRenderer,
  zIndex: 15,
  opacity: 0.65,
  interactive: false
}).addTo(mymap);

//svgobj.bindPopup("SVG vector layer");
//var draggable = new L.Draggable(svgElem);
//draggable.enable(); //make draggable (must set=> interactive: true)
/* SVG OK */

/* set events */
mymap.on("click", onMapClick);
//svgobj.on("click", onSvgClick);

/* other useful settings */
mymap.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
const popup = L.popup(); //leaflet popup object

function onMapClick(e) {
  popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent(e.latlng.toString()).openOn(mymap);
}

/* -------cytoscape-------- */
function lnglat2xy(lon, lat, pars) {
  //let w = pars.width;
  //let h = pars.height;
  let L = pars.lonmax - pars.lonmin; //lonmax2-lonmin
  let B = pars.latmax - pars.latmin;
  let y = ((B - (lat - pars.latmin)) * pars.height) / B;
  let x = ((lon - pars.lonmin) * pars.width) / L;
  return { x: x, y: y };
}

const lngMidLatMid = lnglat2xy(
  (lonmin + lonmax2) / 2,
  (latmin + latmax) / 2,
  params
);

//console.log("lngMidLatMid: "+lngMidLatMid.x+"; "+lngMidLatMid.y);
const bkk = lnglat2xy(100.5348327, 13.7567441, params);
const bda = lnglat2xy(100.4094999, 13.7108552, params);
const hoc = lnglat2xy(100.6076988, 13.5676449, params);
const han = lnglat2xy(100.7522551, 13.6982529, params);
const nay = lnglat2xy(100.4081876, 13.8923587, params);

var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.querySelector("#cyOnSvg"),
  elements: {
    nodes: [
      {
        data: { id: "LL", name: "LowerLeft" },
        classes: "controlpoint",
        position: { x: 0, y: cy_size }
      },
      {
        data: { id: "UL", name: "UpperLeft" },
        classes: "controlpoint",
        position: { x: 0, y: 0 }
      },
      {
        data: { id: "UR", name: "UpperRight" },
        classes: "controlpoint",
        position: { x: cy_size, y: 0 }
      },
      {
        data: { id: "LR", name: "LowerRight" },
        classes: "controlpoint",
        position: { x: cy_size, y: cy_size }
      },
      /* Nodes with (long,lat) coordinates */
      { data: { id: "bkk", name: "A8" }, position: { x: bkk.x, y: bkk.y } },
      { data: { id: "bda", name: "BL38" }, position: { x: bda.x, y: bda.y } },
      { data: { id: "hoc", name: "E23" }, position: { x: hoc.x, y: hoc.y } },
      { data: { id: "han", name: "A1" }, position: { x: han.x, y: han.y } },
      { data: { id: "nay", name: "PP01" }, position: { x: nay.x, y: nay.y } },
    ],
    edges: [
      {
        data: { id: "LLUR", source: "LL", target: "UR" },
        classes: "controlline"
      },
      {
        data: { id: "ULLR", source: "UL", target: "LR" },
        classes: "controlline"
      },
      {
        data: { id: "bkk_bda", source: "bkk", target: "bda" },
        classes: "edge"
      },
      {
        data: { id: "bkk_han", source: "bkk", target: "han" },
        classes: "edge"
      },
      {
        data: { id: "bkk_hoc", source: "bkk", target: "hoc" },
        classes: "edge"
      },
      {
        data: { id: "bkk_nay", source: "bkk", target: "nay" },
        classes: "edge"
      },
    ]
  },
  style: [
      {
      selector: "node",
      style: {
        shape: "hexagon",
        width: "50px",
        height: "50px",
        "background-color": "blue",
        label: "data(name)",
        opacity: 1,
        "text-background-color": "yellow"
      }
    },
      {
      selector: ".controlline",
      style: {
        width: "2px",
        "line-color": "black",
        opacity: 1
      }
    },
      {
      selector: ".edge",
      style: {
        width: "3px",
        "line-color": "red",
        opacity: 1
      }
    },
  ],
    layout: {
    name: "preset"
  }
  });

cy.pan({ x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }); //match TOP-LEFT corner
cy.fit(cy.$("#LLUR"));
```

```css
:root {
  --svg-width: 1600px;
  --svg-height: 1600px;
}

#cyOnSvg{
  /* foreignObject, and canvas */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; //5%;
  height: 100%; //10%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#Svg0{
  /* svg elem */
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--svg-width);
  height: var(--svg-height);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  /*border: 0.5px solid gray;
  border-style: dashed;*/
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mapid { 
  height: 480px; 
  width: 480px;
}

#lorem {
  width: var(--svg-width);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.9.2/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-browser/0.1.0/jquery.browser.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. This definitely clears a lot of blockers for me.

Comment: @rakeshfc The correct way to thank is either or both (1. vote up my answer, 2. click to accept it). You may get some reputation points from doing so.